# Create URL for Google maps with XSLT

Tags: xml, url, xslt, maps

I want to create an url for google maps for my application. My scenario is as described below:

I have XSLT file which generates XML result, this xslt file reads through a list of addresses retrieved from database. so I want to add a link to the address "Map it" link which directly goes to google maps and displays marker with the address shown on maps.

unfortunately my database returns address with blank spaces in it as for e.g. "2313 John Eppes Rd" so I want t replace the spaces with + sign and generate address string as: "2313+John+Eppes+Rd". How can I achive this using  in xslt whose value is $address.

My google mapping looks as below:

```
       <xsl:if test="position() = 3">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
           [url="http://maps.google.com/maps?/zoom=13+size=600x300+maptype=roadmap
          +markers=color:blue+sensor=false+<xsl:value-of select="."/>"] - Map it[/url][br][br]
      </xsl:if>
```

Please let me know how-to form this string with "+" sign.

Thanks,
Vijaya Laxmi.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`translate()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate) function to replace all occurrences of space with a plus.

```
translate($address, ' ', '+')
```